# Why My App Throws No Static Method While It exists

Tags: java, android

I have a java file that contains a static method and after running the app , it shows me that the method does not exist, I decomplied my app source code and found the method exists , so why it throws that Exception[this is the error which is being thrown on Runtime

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXRDv.jpg)

[My App's Runtime Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDxjP.jpg)

Comment: Please share what progress you made on this and where are you facing challenged?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: On a different note, that's a potentially "smelly" amount of `static` in that code, particularly since it's involving state changes. Show more of your code, and definitely not in a phone screenshot. It may be something as simple as forgetting to recompile `ScreenUtil.java`.